# React, redux state is dependent on other redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am getting xhr.js:160 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orderitem/undefined/ 500 (Internal Server Error).
I am calling getOrder() action and then I call getOrderItem(customer=state.order.customer)

How do I wait for the redux state to update then call getOrderItem(), so the Axios request looks like
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orderitem/1/?

react component

```
export class Cart extends Component{

static propTypes = {
    order: PropTypes.object,
    getOrder: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteOrder: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

    orderitem: PropTypes.array,
    getOrderItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    addOrderItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteOrderItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
async componentDidMount(){
    try{
        await this.props.getOrder();
        console.log(this.props.order);
        await this.props.getOrderItem( this.props.order.customer);
        
        
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }

}
render(){
 ...
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    cart: state.cart.items,
    order: state.order.order,
    orderitem: state.orderitem.orderItem,
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, {
        getOrder,
        deleteOrder,
        getOrderItem,
        addOrderItem,
        deleteOrderItem,
    })(Cart)
```

Action Order App

```
export const getOrder = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get('/api/order/', tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ORDER,
        payload: res.data[0],
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Action OrderItem App

```
export const getOrderItem = (customer) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/orderorderitem/${customer}`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ORDERITEM,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you updated the redux state with `await this.props.getOrder();` you need to finish the execution of componentDidMount to let react re-render and update your `this.props`, otherwise `this.props` won't have the new redux state values.

You could put the `getOrderItem` function inside a `componentDidUpdate` and ask about the `this.props.order.customer` like so:

```js
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getOrder();
  }


componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.order?.customer 
      && this.props.order.customer !== this.prevProps.order.customer) {
    this.props.getOrderItem( this.props.order.customer)
  }
}
```